# WM_COMMAND not received in subclassed WinAPI button

Tags: c++, winapi, subclassing, wndproc, wm-command

I have a basic wrapper class for my buttons created in C++ with WinAPI. I try to handle messages but it looks like not everything reaches my `WndProc`

```
class MyButton {
public:
    MyButton(HINSTANCE, HWND);
private:
    HWND _hWnd;
    static LRESULT CALLBACK _WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, UINT_PTR, DWORD_PTR);
};

MyButton::MyButton(HINSTANCE hInst, HWND hParent)
{
    this->_hWnd = CreateWindow(
        TEXT("BUTTON"),
        TEXT("CLICK ME"),
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
        10, 10,
        100, 25,
        hParent,
        NULL,
        hInst,
        this
    );

    SetWindowSubclass(this->_hWnd, this->_WndProc, 1, (DWORD_PTR)this);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MyButton::_WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSub, DWORD_PTR dwRef)
{
    // MessageBox(NULL, L"TEST1", L"TEST1", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

    MyButton *pThis = (MyButton*)dwRef;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        MessageBox(NULL, L"TEST2", L"TEST2", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        break;
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The function is called (*"TEST1"* is shown) but when I click the button, I don't see *"TEST2"*. I also tried with `WM_CREATE` and it doesn't work either. I don't know what messages are passed to `_WndProc`

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the debugger. Set a break point on the line that shows "TEST1", and then see what the values are vs what you expect them to be. Also, is `_WndProc` static? I think it should be.

Comment: Some advice -- for a complex API such as the Windows API, you should be attempting to get the program to work *without* using a C++ wrapper.   If you don't know how to get your program to work using `C`, then making a C++ wrapper for it is not going to go too well.  Also, with the Windows API, have programs or source that accomplish what you are trying to accomplish, such as examples from Charles Petzold's book and others.  -- *I also tried with WM_CREATE* -- Trying to guess at what to do with the Windows API is a losing proposition.

Comment: `WM_COMMAND` is sent to the parent in this instance. You'll need the parent window to reflect the message back to your control.

Comment: I think you should make an identifier for the control as long as being a child of the main window. You set it as a child `WS_CHILD` but passed `NULL` as `(HMENU)id`.

Comment: You don't receive `WM_CREATE` because you subclass only _after_ `CreateWindow()`, which sends this message. So it's simply too late to receive that message. If you want to receive `WM_CREATE` you have to register your own window class using `RegisterClass()`.

Comment: Frameworks like MFC provide ways to reroute `WM_COMMAND` and other messages from the parent back to the sender and handle it there. This is called [message reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeah46xd.aspx). You could implement something similar.

Comment: @zett42: If you want to receive `WM_CREATE` in a custom window procedure, you can install a [CBT hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977.aspx) and respond to the `HCBT_CREATEWND` code, to attach the C++ class instance to the window handle. That's how MFC accomplishes routing **all** messages (including `WM_NCCREATE`) to the subclassed window procedure.

Comment: Handling button presses inside the button instance itself is fairly questionable design. A button is a control with a visual representation, that a user can interact with. And that's really it. The control parent owns the control, and should establish the connection with the business logic, to respond to user interface interactions. Why do you want to put business logic into your button control?